# NoHostAvailableException in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I need to make a presentation+ connection to cassandra for classes. After quite a big hussle I left behind other kinds of errors, but I'm getting stuck here, where it seems not to get the address of the Keyspace.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException;

public class conectaradb {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
    Cluster cluster;
     Session sesion;

     cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();

     sesion= cluster.connect("ejemplodb");

     ResultSet resultado= sesion.execute("select * from empleados");
     String nombreemp,fecha,cargo;
     double comision,salario;
     int empno;

     for (Row row:resultado) {
         empno=row.getInt("empno");
         cargo=row.getString("cargo");
         comision=row.getDouble("comision");
         fecha=row.getString("fechaing");
         nombreemp=row.getString("nombreempno");
         salario=row.getDouble("salario");
         System.out.println(empno+" "+cargo+" "+comision+" "+fecha+" "+nombreemp+" "+salario);
     }  
     cluster.close();

 }catch(NoHostAvailableException e) {
 System.out.println(e.getErrors());
}


}

}
```

I'd be glad if someone can Identify where is the error, I think I have the yaml file right. I get the error when the code reaches the localhost on addcontactpoint: "All hosts tried for query failed".
After a .getError I get a "TransportException". I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Update rpc_broadcast_address in cassandra.yaml to a valid IP; since rpc_address is 0.0.0.0. Then try and connect via Java with that IP after restarting Cassandra.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/address_resolution/

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the yaml file in the comments. First of all the rpc_address is wrong, it should not be 0.0.0.0. But you fixed that already.

The next error is that you set native_transport_port: 9042 and rpc_port: 9042. You can't use the same port for both interfaces. Thrift (rpc) is the old interface and should not really be used so if I where you I would set start_rpc: false, but of course changing the port would be enough. Look here for more information: https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/making-the-change-from-thrift-to-cql

If you get any more errors let me know and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

what version of JDBC driver is your application using?
That error can also occur if you are using an incompatible driver.

Check you have a Driver that's compatible with Cassandra 3.11
(version 3.x and later)

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/javaDrivers.html

Comment: I'm trying to use the driver from the Build Path -> add External Libraries. The link you sent me gets me to a maven piece of code, and actually I don't even know what's maven. Isn't there a driver I can add to the libraries?

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?
In that link there is also an option for a tarball which you can download instead.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qdNP4 There you have the drivers I have imported. Please let me know if they are right.

Comment: looks ok, you have v3.3 drivers. Is that the version you started with?

Comment: I have changed drivers here and there, I think I started with that one, before I asked for help here.